# stop feeling like gorilla meaning?

Tags: phrases, idiom-meaning

A person asked another person:

> have you stopped feeling like gorilla now?

I really didn't get the meaning. Is this meant to be something funny or insulting?

Comment: Without further context I would *guess* that for "gorilla" you can think of King Kong up the Empire State Building swatting planes, i.e. "angry sub-human, incapable of speech, only capable of hitting things". If I'm right, then they're asking if you've calmed down since earlier. Or an alternative explanation: gorillas are much hairier than humans. Is it possible you've shaved or had a haircut or something, so they're asking if you prefer the feeling of having less hair?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It might be both funny and insulting, as the meaning of sentence may depend on the situation when something is said. 
"Feel like gorilla" may have been said to imply the sense of "being different from human and doing something similar to gorilla.